# pivot_wider for multiple choice questionnaire

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

have a dataset from a survey. 2 questions have multiple choice options and it doesn't allow me to use `pivot_wider`

here is a sample data.

```
nam=c("per_id","quest","answ")
per_id=c("0012","0023","0045","0003","0003","0045","0003","0012","0023","0004","0004","0001","0005","0546","0001","0546","0005","0004","0004")
quest=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
answ=c("Self","Self","Self","Self","Father","Sister","Daughter","Mother","Father","Self","Father","X1","Y1","Z1","Y1","Z2","X1","X1","X1")

df=cbind.data.frame(per_id,quest,answ)
names(df)=nam
```

what I want to have is

[image: here]

Comment: Quick comment: having an object (`names`) and a function (`names()`) with the same name is generally not a good idea!

Comment: True, this was a small example so It was not causing any issue but you are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the following approach using `split` + `Reduce` + `merge` based on unique rows.

### Approach

```r
l = lapply(split(df, df$quest), \(x) { x = unique(x); x$quest = NULL; x })
# names(l$A)[2] = "A"
# names(l$B)[2] = "B"
# in case you have more than two quests: 
l = lapply(names(l), \(x) setNames(l[[x]], c(names(l[[x]])[1], x)))
Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), l)
```

### Result

```r
   per_id        A    B
1    0001     <NA>   X1
2    0001     <NA>   Y1
3    0003     Self <NA>
4    0003   Father <NA>
5    0003 Daughter <NA>
6    0004     Self   X1
7    0004   Father   X1
8    0005     <NA>   Y1
9    0005     <NA>   X1
10   0012     Self <NA>
11   0012   Mother <NA>
12   0023     Self <NA>
13   0023   Father <NA>
14   0045     Self <NA>
15   0045   Sister <NA>
16   0546     <NA>   Z1
17   0546     <NA>   Z2
```

### Data

```r
df = structure(list(per_id = c("0012", "0023", "0045", "0003", "0003", 
"0045", "0003", "0012", "0023", "0004", "0004", "0001", "0005", 
"0546", "0001", "0546", "0005", "0004", "0004"), quest = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), answ = c("Self", "Self", "Self", "Self", 
"Father", "Sister", "Daughter", "Mother", "Father", "Self", "Father", 
"X1", "Y1", "Z1", "Y1", "Z2", "X1", "X1", "X1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: And then we can rbind list objects 
`library(tidyverse)
lo1 =l %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -person_id) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))`

Comment: I do not understand your comment. If you do `result = Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), l)` you do not need `bind_rows()` or (base) `do.call(rbind, >sth<)` or, in some cases, `list2DF(>sth<)`/`list2DF(t(>sth<))`. `result` is already in long fomrat. The base equivalent to `result |> filter(!is.na(value))` is `result[!is.na(result$value), ]`.